# How to find column with specific row is zero in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframe like below.

```
    index col_A    col_B    col_C   col_D   col_E
      a     12       15      28       34     23
      b     23       37      46       34     92
      c     34       32      24       93     12 
      d     12       0        1       0      0
```

I want output like below.

```
    index     col_B   col_D   col_E
      a        15      34     23
      b        37      34     92
      c        32      93     12 
      d        0        0      0
```

The output frame condition is like if there is 0 in **index d** row. It should be in output dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select index `d` and then filter by another [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with `:` for all rows and condition for filter columns:

```
df = df.loc[:, df.loc['d'].eq(0)]
print (df)
       col_B  col_D  col_E
index                     
a         15     34     23
b         37     34     92
c         32     93     12
d          0      0      0
```